# Ubuntu 20.04: Order of Application Instances

Tags: 20.04

Ubuntu 18 and below used to have the following behavior:

If two instances of an application were open, the most recently used instance would go to the top of the Quick View list when you click on the Dock. In Ubuntu 20.04+, I seem to see that the first opened instance is always first, and the 2nd instance I start is always second.

In Ubuntu 20.04+, I want to restore the old behavior. This image shows what I am observing on Ubuntu 20.04:

[image]

In this example on Ubuntu 20.04, I open a terminal, type 1, open a second terminal, type 2, and then click on the Terminal icon in the Docker. In the Quick Preview of open instances, I want second terminal I opened to be at the top (like in Ubuntu 18.04) because it is the most recently used terminal. I cannot find a setting for this.

Comment: Please clear up your release details; you mention 18 & 20 through your question (thus Ubuntu Core 18 & Ubuntu Core 20?) but have tagged 20.04?  20 & 20.04 are different products; 20 being the *snap* only flavor of 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior where the popup previews would be ordered according to Most Recent Use was changed to a fixed order. This way, the behavior is consistent with that of the icons themselves, which also do not change order according to which application you used last. That prevents the need for you to scan these window previews every time again in the same session and avoids you from having to discover whether the windows you are looking for is at the top, at the bottom or somewhere in the middle this time. You know a particular document is the first, another one is the second right from the bat.

Developers of the Dash to Dock/Ubuntu dock extension did not leave an option to revert this behavior, so restoring the old behavior would require changing source code.